change KeyboardInterrupt to 'enter'
I have the following code:
import time

def run_indefinitely():
    while True:
        # code to run indefinitely goes here
        print("Running indefinitely...")
        time.sleep(1)  

try:
    
        # Run the code indefinitely until Enter key is pressed
        run_indefinitely()            

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Loop interrupted by user")

Is there a way to break out of the while loop by hitting 'enter' instead of ctrl+C ?

This is surprisingly tricky to do in Python. The technique involves spawning a worker thread to interrupt us later.
Using python-readchar:
import os
import signal
import sys
import time
from threading import Timer

from readchar import readkey  # pip install readchar

def wait_for(key, timeout):
    """wait `timeout` seconds for user to press `key`"""
    pid = os.getpid()
    sig = signal.CTRL_C_EVENT if os.name == "nt" else signal.SIGINT
    timer = Timer(timeout, lambda: os.kill(pid, sig))
    timer.start()
    while True:
        k = readkey()
        print(f"received {k!r}")
        if k == key:
            timer.cancel()  # cancel the timer
            print("breaking")
            break

def run_indefinitely():
    while True:
        print("Running indefinitely...")
        try:
            wait_for(key="\n", timeout=1)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            continue
        else:
            break

run_indefinitely()
print("Loop interrupted by user")

Using pynput:
import os
import signal
import time

from pynput import keyboard  # pip install pynput

pid = os.getpid()

def on_press(key):
    if key is keyboard.Key["enter"]:
        sig = signal.CTRL_C_EVENT if os.name == "nt" else signal.SIGINT
        os.kill(pid, sig)

with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as k:
    try:
        for i in range(10):
            print("Running indefinitely...")
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

print("Loop interrupted by user")


Here's a simple way:
import time
import keyboard  

def run_indefinitely():
    while True:
        # Your code to run indefinitely goes here
        print("Running indefinitely...")
        time.sleep(1) 
        if keyboard.is_pressed('enter'):
            break


   
run_indefinitely()

        


    
print("how now brown cow")


@wim take a look at me answer below

Is that https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard ?  It requires root to work on Linux, which is unacceptable IMO.

@wim have you used pynput?

I have not tried it before. It looks like a good library, edited an example into my answer. The idea is similar to my existing answer, i.e. using a listener thread.

@wim I updated your answer (not sure if I'm supposed to do that) but what do you think of that approach?

I think you should edit it into your answer, not mine.

The two other answers on this post are great, here's another solution using keyboard.wait().
import keyboard

keyboard.wait('enter') #wait for user to press enter (basically the same as a while loop, the program runs forever until enter is pressed)

raise KeyboardInterrupt("You pressed enter!") 

I would also like to point out that this method uses less CPU (as mentioned in the documentation of keyboard) than @DCR's answer. In the comments section, I agree with the fact that pynput is probably a superior library than keyboard.
Here's a few other ways you could do it (however in my opinion, not as efficient):
import keyboard

flag = False

def onHotkey():
    global flag
    flag = True #if enter is pressed, flag it

while True:
    if flag:
        break

And a solution using pynput:
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def onPress(key):
    if key == Key.enter:
        return False #stops the listener thread by returning False

with Listener(on_press=onPress) as listener:
    listener.join() #after the listener is stopped, the next line of code executes

raise KeyboardInterrupt("You pressed enter!")

 
